# facebook php logout issue

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have been using this code for facebook sdk logout but its not working. However i can login iwth it successfully. Here is the code.

```
if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'user_about_me, user_hometown')
);
}

?>

<?php if ($user){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout Here</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: The `$user` variable on the top is coming from `$facebook->getUser()` ?

Comment: yes it is coming from $facebook->getUser()

Answer (score 1):

The default Facebook SDK [uses](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L51) php's built in session implementation to store it's data. Among these the last logged in [user id](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L43).

When your user clicks on the logout link, facebook will log her out, and send her back to your site, however facebook can't delete the values in your site's `$_SESSION`. Add a `next` parameter to the `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()` so facebook will send the user back there, and you can clear the whole session (after all the user has logged out) with [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

If you don't want to clear the whole session just the facebook specific values, there's a method for that called [destroySession](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1187) on the `BaseFacebook` class (for some reason not listed in offical sdk docs).